# Currency Fields is not allowing decimal places In visual force page for Swedish Currency

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, force.com-sites, force.com

I have a client from Swedish and they use **Swedish Krona** currency. I have created one VF page and added it to force.com and the user will update or insert data.

In salesforce, when Swedish currency is in use, a dot(.) is considered as a comma(,) and a comma(,) as blank space. It throws an error when I use a decimal point in that VF page but it accepts decimal points on the record page.

User Locale is Swedish (Sweden) and I put that VF page on force.com site for getting data from users.

It's been 2 days I tried everything but I am not able to find it what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: What is the locale of the user entering the data?  Please [edit] your post to include that information.  Also you have tagged force.com sites on your question - is this page running on a Site?  Please include more detail in your original post.

Comment: Just to confirm - you set the site guest user's locale?  Site > Public Access Settings > Assigned Users?

Comment: Yes, I set the site guest user's locale. But I check this issue on the VF page preview it's also not working with the VF page